# Magento 2.4.0 issue after upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I have upgraded from Magento 2.3.6-p1 to Magento 2.4.0 all went well regarding

```
composer update 
bin/magento s:up 
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* 
bin/magento s:d:c 
bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

when trying to access the site it shows the below error both on the frontend and admin panel.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface::get($name) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id) in /home/techhopc/mysite.com/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceLocatorInterface.php on line 16
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by changing PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4